# What could cause sex roles to be reversed?

Tags: sex

I'd like to get an idea for what could be the reasons that women were the ones who actively look most on the beginning  for sex (meaning that just by physical appearance they'd get aroused enough to have sex with that person) and men the ones who are less likely to accept sex the described way, maintaining these four concepts:

·The ratio between men and women is approximately 1:1 as nowadays.

·Women are the ones that keep on getting pregnant, if conception happens.

·Risk of STD is the same as it is now.

·Contraceptive methods are more are less as the ones that exist now with similar effectiveness in STD and pregnancy prevention.

It's possible to either have changed biological reasons or social ones as long as they aren't too fantastic.

I mean right now, there are women who are nymphomaniacs and men that even consider having sex even sickening, but those cases are usually rare. Anyway it's likely that the biological and social reasons that cause those behaviors in those people could be extended to a whole society, by favoring those biological and social differences that cause those behaviors on those people to the whole population.

Any idea on how a situation like this could end up happening?

Comment: It's pretty reductive to think that "sex roles" is only who the initiating partner is. In fact there are cultures on earth that exist today where women are the active partners when it comes to initiating sexual relationships.

Comment: Of course, but the worldwide situation is more like what I'm describing, at least that's the impression I have.

Comment: Your premise is flawed because it supposes that men are always the the initiating partner.

Comment: I'm not saying about initiating partner. I'm talking about sex search. The biological differences in wanting sex make men more likely to initiate the search than women as they usually want it more than women.

Comment: That isn't backed by any scientific evidence.

Comment: You are so wrong it's funny. You are describing a stereotyped version of the late Victorian society. For a more real description of how men and women look for sex you should read a modern book such as Boccaccio's *[Decameron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Decameron)* (first published in the 1350s, in manuscript form). There are many English translations; the oldest was published in 1620, the [most recent](https://www.amazon.com/Decameron-Giovanni-Boccaccio-ebook/dp/B00CNEO9IU/) was made by Wayne Rebhorn. It's a good book, very entertaining and very educative. Not for children.

Comment: @AlexP What do you not undertand about women behaving like men does with sex now and men like women? Maybe the actively look for sex is a bit confusing, I recognize that, but from context it should be clear that it's about a change in attitudes. Being women the ones who would behave like  men and viceversa (the difference can be seen in things like this http://bit.ly/1ojbWbK or this http://bit.ly/2ebllBV). And of course men don't only look for sex.

Comment: @JesúsGómez: What you don't understand is that how men and women behave is historically determined, that is, it varies from place to place and from time to time. As regards your example, women consume as much porn as men; it is _different_ porn, and their version of porn is not classified as porn by the men who make the laws; examples include *Vogue*, *Cosmopolitan*, the *Harlequin* romances, *Fifty shades of Gray* etc. Yes, there is a physiological difference in that men prefer to look at straightforward pictures and women prefer more complicated stories. *Vive la différence*.

Comment: @JesúsGómez Not to seem condescending, but it fascinates me how fundimentally wrong someone can be.

Comment: @JesúsGómez This...seems to be a social construct and not a biological one. In some of Medieval lit there was a lot of talk about how women were randy and could never truly be satisfied with the amount of sex they got. Because women can orgasm multiple times. And men are satisfied after like...a few minutes or whatever, but here we are asking for more. We ladies be insatiable. My point is that you are absolutely incorrect in saying it's biological, that men want it more than women. Women wanting more time spent on the sex--maybe even more often than men, isn't all that rare.

Comment: @ErinThursby I haven't said it's all biological, but I think it also influences, being the one getting pregnant makes women to choose more their partner, female orgams are bigger, they usually have a maternal instict so they choose more in which would be the potential father of their children. They can be insatiable with a man they choose, but outside that I think it's rare that a women would be willing to have sex with 7 unknown men in 7 days, when if she's midly attractive she could. A man would be more likely to do that if he could, but even if he's over the top attractive it would be hard.

Comment: The last part is the sex drive I'm talking about. I don't also understand the negative votes, I haven't said anything about those behaviors being good or bad. By the way, I haven't problem with neither of them.

Comment: I edited my question, hope it's more clear now.

Comment: I think you need to edit some more, and make it clear that you have edited. Your actual question is more about "many different partners" than it is about sex drive, I think.

Answer (score 5):

**Women want to have sex**

Maybe I'm not really understanding the question but women had always looked for sex as much as men, if not even more. When a woman finds a man attractive she is going  to produce the situations that allow intimacy.

When you said that a woman is less inclined to accept sex, is the wrong interpretation. What are you seeing is that they don't want to have sex with someone that they don't find attractive.

**For example:** As a man it may be the case that you don't find other guys attractive or feel any desire to be with them. That is the same (lack of) feeling that a woman has with guys that she doesn't find attractive.

Comment: Yeah of course they want. But I think it's pretty obvious that if you get 100 males and 100 girls, where all males would see all females as attractive and viceversa, the number of females that would accept having sex with a man they just met would be way lower than the number of males that would have sex with a female they have just met.

Comment: I once found a scientific study about that, I can search and link it, anyway I think it's pretty obvious.

Comment: @JesúsGómez: What you say is simply that men will initiate more attempts at chatting up women then women would inititiate at chatting up men. Women have good reasons to be wary of sex with a complete stranger -- in a one-on-one situation most women are physically weaker than most men, so some selectivity is advantageous; and women do have to think about the possible results of a one night stand. In the end, most such attempts would be rejected, and just about the same number of men as women will actually have sex.

Comment: Simplified version: when a woman say no it doesn't necessarily mean that she doesn't want sex, but it certainly means she doesn't want sex with you.

Comment: @AlexP, I didn't want to mean about men make more attempts, I'm telling about looking more actively for sex, not necessarily about chatting up. What you say is right, but as I'm telling on my question there are even nymphomaniac women who don't even care much about how the man looks as long as they can have sex, their sex needs make them to forget those dangers, in the search of having sex. I think it wouldn't be impossible that most of them ended behaving like that if those biological and social changes were spread to the rest of women.

Comment: Yeah I think what he's really asking is what would it take for a system of polyandry to take hold. That's the angle I took it from, anyway. The question does kind of reek of sexism as written.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember my high school biology correctly, generally speaking, the female sex drive peaks during the period of potential conception (aka, "periodic") where men basically have the same drive all the time.  To males who don't understand this, it appears that women simply have less of a sex drive than men.  Note, however, that this is 100% biological.  Outlying cases (e.g., your somewhat insensitive reference to nymphomaniac women and impotent males... you do know that both mean **AND** women can become addicted to sex or suffer impotency, right?) are irrelevant to the question.

What I don't understand is why you want to focus only on this.  How would society be different if the female sex drive were constant and the male sex drive periodic?  To begin with you'd have to justify that in your story, and since the drive is 100% connected with the reproductive cycle, you kinda can't and leave everything the same as you suggested in your question.

Finally, note that the Star Trek NG episode "[Angel One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_One)" dealt with the idea of gender role reversal (the women were generally taller, more muscular, and more aggressive, the men smaller, weaker, and more docile).  Maybe you want to check that out.

Comment: I don't want to focus only on this, it's only a part.

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of people are having trouble with this question because it seems to be sexist. I am going to come at it from a biologic standpoint, and perhaps with better research you can frame it in a way that isn't offensive to many here.

Pregnancy is the root of the reason why culturally, most women don't want to sleep around as much as men do, with many different partners. You are not changing that.

The reason for the difference is COST. Men currently can breed with any woman, at no real cost to them biologically, but women, because they have a chance of pregnancy, look at it differently.

So it's now time to take a look at [polyandry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyandry_in_nature) in the animal kingdom, wherein the lady animals breed with as many dudes as possible. This has to have a biologic advantage.

Strangely enough:

> According to Gordon G. Gallup, as a form of adapting to multiple mating in females, human penile shape is indicative of an evolutionary history of polyandry. Male humans evolved to have a wedge- or spoon-shaped glans and to perform repeated thrusting motions during copulation in order to draw foreign semen back away from the cervix and thus to compete with sperm of other males.

Here are some of the biologic reasons for polyandry in the animal kingdom:

- Males kill babies they don't think are theirs. If you breed with
  everyone, then they won't kill your baby.
- Paternity sharing. In one species of frog, the lovely lady got three or four male frogs helping with the eggs.
- Sperm fitness competition! Mate with multiple males and only the strong sperm survive! This means your baby has a head start in life.

Look too at the [Callitrichidae](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/46874/265_2004_Article_BF00295541.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), which is a type of monkey. Only one female in the group at a time tends to be fertile, and everyone breeds with her. Males do a lot of the child-rearing, though it is communal. Polyandry is the most common system that callitrichidae use, but depending on the ages and makeup of their society, they can shift to other systems, and can change when a new female enters the group. I've linked a scientific paper on it, but if it's too dense there's this [link](https://www.primates.com/primate/callitrichidae.html), which explains the expulsion of males in some groups, after the children are old enough, and this link (scroll down to behavior) where they talk about the [flexibility](http://www.encyclopedia.com/environment/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/new-world-monkeys-ii-marmosets-tamarins-and-goeldis-monkeys-callitrichidae) of their breeding.

You'll be able to start to answer your own question by looking for patterns in polyandry animals. One thing I have noticed is multiple births seem to be more common in this type of set up. Do look at the link above on polyandry in the animal kingdom. You can start with that wiki link and research from there. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There may be many "social" reason to construct societies with the strange rules, but what you ask is ingrained in our reproductive system.

Root reason is to spawn a child a woman needs nine months, while a male may take less than nine minutes.

Given that Natural Selection favors good choices it is scarcely surprising we actually do:

- women have best chose accurately partner because they'll be stuck for a long time with results; I mean: aside from any social or cultural bias, half of genetic material comes from the father and that *is* going to matter (whatever do-gooder sociologists will try to tell you), so to have a better chance to win in the Evolution Lottery women need to concentrate their efforts into getting the best children possible in the time frame.
- men, OTOH, have no such limitation, so, while they are looking for the "best partner", there's nothing refraining them to fecundate whatever woman is willing (or can be coerced).

All this is, obviously, not fully valid in any modern society (actually just writing this down I risk badly), but imprints from a remote past (from even before humankind existed) are deeply ingrained in our instincts.

This means it is quite easy to imagine (actually no imagination is needed, they exist) societies where women make advances and males wait for those, but it is difficult to imagine males routinely turning down offers.

Situation would be completely different if men would be in position to copulate successfully only once a year (for example); in that case also males would have to chose very carefully where to spend their precious chances.

Modern societies have (mostly) disconnected sex from procreation and thus these instincts are bound to wane, sooner or later; unfortunately, if reverting the process will take the same time it took to build it in the first place, we will have to wait a few million years to be cleansed.